# how to remove the second list in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have textfile full of this list:

```
om.troook1                                                                                                                                       
afmm1989                                                                                                                                          aalkhulaifi2525                                                                                                                                           atamayz                                                                                                                                           esraa_e10                                                                                                                                           worldwise_hmak                                                                                                                                           a.17.salolo
aldana_alshmmary                                                                                                                                          isra_00f                                                                                                                                           5atheet_38li                                                                                                                                           raedalmajed80                                                                                                                                           6ooney11                                                                                                                                           3dooo17
alatwah44                                                                                                                                          7bw__                                                                                                                                           59po                                                                                                                                           ___miral.2                                                                                                                                           howassad                                                                                                                                           duhdugfgdskbyhcgfh
l250j                                                                                                                                          pluvas.jr29                                                                                                                                           hmaad_rfaao                                                                                                                                           _albtoul_3                                                                                                                                           fheed_alsenawy                                                                                                                                           a______ziz
78__na                                                                                                                                          reemahals89                                                                                                                                           ahmad.jowhar                                                                                                                                           bee3_u                                                                                                                                           fad.11224                                                                                                                                           mitchi_minouche
salehalbekhet                                                                                                                                          iam121__                                                                                                                                           ihia.76                                                                                                                                           jr3t_aml                                                                                                                                           yournextride                                                                                                                                           bagais_omar
al_aml_2                                                                                                                                          irox_305                                                                                                                                           1gmk                                                                                                                                           __almlak                                                                                                                                           faisal4557                                                                                                                                           wtfariiana
7ii_z                                                                                                                                          mubarakqurris                                                                                                                                           a_0555974170                                                                                                                                           m_azaadi_q8                                                                                                                                           abooodi1235                                                                                                                                           bbefsalam
aied_alshahrani                                                                                                                                          23w3                                                                                                                                           qqwweerr1235                                                                                                                                           noor_fha                                                                                                                                           hiplikejacobilyy                                                                                                                                           rshd2693
alanouoood                                                                                                                                          anoir.20                                                                                                                                           ahmadou11                                                                                                                                           alrssam1                                                                                                                                           aboooood7778                                                                                                                                           amayraraaqiy
mashan_mneef                                                                                                                                          fofo._._._._._7                                                                                                                                           abd212398                                                                                                                                           xxwaleedoxx                                                                                                                                           7.rxri                                                                                                                                           abdulrahman1771
neima44                                                                                                                                          n.5133                                                                                                                                           dgff3922                                                                                                                                           loaykhalil13                                                                                                                                           8cxm                                                                                                                                           yousifalmulhim
mhmdly9305                                                                                                                                          tlalal___shammry25                                                                                                                                           alhnoooooooooffffff                                                                                                                                           desielvita                                                                                                                                           4mot                                                                                                                                           al3nze_vib_1
banyyanal3rjane95                                                                                                                                          azeez__28                                                                                                                                           fah956                                                                                                                                           dl3_kla93                                                                                                                                           alfaraj15_                                                                                                                                           bostr_5
khaledh139                                                                                                                                          sootk_2012                                                                                                                                           almlek_1985                                                                                                                                           s.lfyf                                                                                                                                           4fal                                                                                                                                           imlzoord
__alnaef                                                                                                                                          fmt2060                                                                                                                                           fufo_x_o                                                                                                                                           l4xj                                                                                                                                           aljoker_rab_24                                                                                                                                           aaaaaa88990
omsaad_h                                                                                                                                          alhot_king_delivery                                                                                                                                           nov.h79                                                                                                                                           xhatem9                                                                                                                                           reem_____7                                                                                                                                           alrashdi.a
bshbshsh.85x                                                                                                                                          h_s_h_s_502
```

How to remove the right usernames, and keep the one in the left using notepad++ regex?

Comment: Maybe `^(\S+).*` --> `$1`?

Comment: @wiktorstribizew it works, but how to remove the empty lines as well?

Comment: See my answer, I added `(?:\R\s*)?` there.

Comment: If any of the solutions work for you, please consider accepting that answer

Answer (score 1):

[`.*`](https://regex101.com/r/nD0jO4/1) and replace with nothing to try.

Answer (score 0):

use a regex, match on `.*_+.*\r\n`, and replace with the empty string?
In this case, all usernames with _ are replaced.